# Python module vs class confusion

Tags: python, gdb

I'm trying to use Python to customize my GDB sessions. I'm copying code from GDB docs, but instead of working properly, they give errors. Confusing ones. I'm a Python noob, so to be honest, the error makes no sense, neither the fix.

```
class MyFrameDecorator(gdb.FrameDecorator):
   # Blah, blah.

# TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Say what now? Where does this '2 arguments vs. 3' come from? I see zero arguments. The following code compiles without complaints:

```
class MyFrameDecorator(gdb.FrameDecorator.FrameDecorator):
   # Blah, blah.
```

Why? I don't get it. Why does repeating the class name fix the type error? Note that GDB automatically adds `import gdb` to all python scripts so that is not the issue (in fact, when the code compiles it doesn't have `import gdb` in it).

Update:

Since people requested a link to the GDB docs:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Frame-Filter.html#Writing-a-Frame-Filter

Comment: `gdb.FrameDecorator` seems to be a module. In that module, there is a class named `FrameDecorator`. In general, this is not the case, this may be due to someone not following Python style conventions (which would avoid some of this ambiguity).

Comment: can you please provide a link to the documentation you say you are copying?

Comment: so, for example, if I created a python package, so a directory named `Foo` with an empty `__init__.py` in it. In that directory, I put a python script, `Bar.py` and inside that script, I just have `Bar = 42`, then if I `import foo.Bar` I will have imported a module, `foo.Bar`, that module, would have a name in it's namespace, `Foo`, so `foo.Bar.Bar` would evaluate to `42`.

Comment: The `FrameDecorator` _module_ contains a `FrameDecorator` _class_. So, to get the class you do `gdb.FrameDecorator.FrameDecorator` or `from FrameDecorator import FrameDecorator`. This isn't particularly common or a part of the language itself. Its just that whoever wrote the FrameDecorator class needed to put it into a module named _something_ and this is what they chose.